# Copying tar.gz libraries to apache-beam workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, setuptools

I hope that you are all well.
I would like to copy a tools library into the worker machines and uses the setup.py file. I have update the CUSTOM_COMMANDS:

```
 CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
  ["wget", "-O", "/usr/local/sratoolkit.tar.gz","http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sdk/current/sratoolkit.current-centos_linux64.tar.gz"],
  ["tar", "-xzf", "/usr/local/sratoolkit.tar.gz","-C","/usr/local/"]]
```

When I am looking for the execution files at the /user/local folder, I can not find the tools that I have copied to the worker.
What is the right & easiest way to copy tools libraries into the worker machines?
I was able to get the expected behavior of the local runner and now it's a matter of finding the right way to reproduce it for the dataflow runner.

I am using python 3.5 with the latest apache-beam 2.20 and latest dataflow
Thanks a lot,
eilalan

Answer (score 1):

The worker machines are setup separately and might not be able download files over the internet.

One way to do it would be uploading the files manually to gcs using `gsutil cp -r /mytools gs://my-bucket/mytools` and then copy all files as the first custom command using `gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/mytools /mytools`

And then execute the appropriate custom commands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it seems that the setup.py is running fine. so i assume that the copy is being performed. If I dont have any other option, I will use your suggestion. Thx